# Dudas sobre configuracion de Github

Tags: github, instalacion

estoy comenzando con todo esto
Mi sistema operativo es MAC
tengo dificultades con la instalacion de git
Me aparece esto y creo que es porque configuré mal el git
como puedo ir hacia atrás?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Ahí no hay lío. Lo que pasa es que estás parado en el directorio base de tu usuario y pues, git te dice que ahí no hay ningún repositorio y los archivos no están siendo seguidos para subir sus cambios a un repositorio remoto. De paso, te dice que la carpeta .Trash tiene permisos que no dejan que la manipule git.

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. Además, pon en el título el problema específico que estás teniendo. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].